# Retrieve SQLite item ID from views I added dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a list of views dynamically that contain names of players retrieved from an SQLite database.

```
public class PlayerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout llPlayers;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private List<Player> players;
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        players = db.getAllPlayers();
        for (Player p : players) {
            addPlayer(p.getId() + ". " + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName());
        }
        //...
    }

    private void addPlayer(String name) {
        TextView tvPlayerName = new TextView(PlayerListActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int hd = getDimenInDp(5); // getDimenInDp translates Pixels into DPs
        int wd = getDimenInDp(10);
        p.setMargins(wd, hd, wd, hd);
        tvPlayerName.setLayoutParams(p);
        tvPlayerName.setText(name);
        tvPlayerName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        llPlayers.addView(tvPlayerName);
        llPlayers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) {
             //...
        }  

    }
    //...
}
```

What I want to is to when I click on each name I get the details in another activity or fragment or even in that same activity. To do that I thought about retrieving the ID of the SQLite item and fetch the item from database and work with it.

I tried a few tricks but none of them worked so please tell me how to do this. Any advice or suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Comment: What happened now you are getting error or what?

Comment: One more thing you need to initialize your list List<Player> players= new ArrayList<Player>.

Comment: use `ListView` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`, if you do that `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` method will give you valid `id` in its last paramater

Comment: @Dilip I don't get any errors. I tried to pass the id to the addPlayer method but I get the last id only.

Comment: @pskink I thought abt that but I want something simpler if its possible. If not i'll go for that..

Comment: you can do that with 5 lines of code... it is not simple? something more or less like [this](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Comment: @pskink please post an answer!

Comment: whats unclear with the link i posted?

Comment: @pskink i just didnt try it yet